# session timeout in spring boot + React

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, session-timeout

I am able to configure session timeout in web.xml, but after session timeout getting errors from react side.
using spring security and jwt token.

WebSecurity.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailServiceImpl userDetails;

    @Autowired
    JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetails).passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/index*", "/static/**", "/*.js", "/*.json", "/*.ico", "/*.png")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/login", "/", "/actuator").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate/**", "/identity/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().cors().and()
                .exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I tried sessionManagement().InvalidSessionURL("url") but on login it always redirect to invalid url only.
There is no api for login, we are loading from React directly.
Please let me know how to redirect to login page on session timeout ? and how to handle errors from react side ?

Comment: I got work around or may be solution, after session timeout we can check if it is new or old session in all apis. if(request.getSession().isNew()) {  logger.info("New session");  // We can send some status code to React and based on that redirect to login }. Any other better solution ? or it will work

Comment: Now we are handling it from React side.

Comment: How are you handling from react side?

Comment: search and try this import { useIdleTimer } from 'react-idle-timer'

Comment: okay .. Thank you @Hitesh Kumar